Why does Ba'alzamon threaten Rand to strangle him with the corpse of the Great Serpent?
In The Eye of the World chapter 24 Rand meet Ba'alzamon in the nightmare. Ba'alzamon say:

The Light will not help you and the Eye of the World will not serve you. You are my hound and if you will not course at my command, I will strangle you with the corpse of the Great Serpent!

What does «the corpse of the Great Serpent» mean? Is it related to the serpent on Aes Sedai rings? Or is it just an abstract threat that He use to intimidate Rand, and it doesn't really mean anything?

The Great Serpent is another way of representing the Wheel of Time - yes, it is linked to the Aes Sedai rings.  It is an intimidation tactic, using 'sacred' symbols as things he can destroy and use to his purpose.  It also implies that he will destroy creation and/or remake it in his image.
Blind the Eye, break the wheel, kill the serpent are all used as 'terrible threats' in the books from Dark Friends.

The Great Serpent is an older symbol for time and/or eternity, much like The Wheel. The Aes Sedai ring is representing the Great Serpent.
Out of universe, this is clearly something that Jordan imported into WoT directly from real world ancient mythology - the symbol Ouroboros, which has the same meaning.
Striving to stop time itself/undoing creation is a recurring thing that Ba'alzamon is striving for. Not necessarily something that they actually have the ability to see through, so it might be an empty threat. The reason why Ba'alzamon said a lot of things like this, including trying to make Rand serve him, becomes much clearer once we learn more about him later on in the books.
(Major spoiler:)

 Since Ba'alzamon is not actually the Dark One but Ishamael. And he is stark raving mad. Being a ta'veren like the Dragon Reborn, he sees himself and Lews Therin fighting the same fight over and over for all of eternity, as noted in the very first prologue in the books. He thinks the only end to this eternal conflict would be to either stop time itself or have the Dragon join the Shadow. He also thinks that the Dark One's ultimate goal is to destroy time and all of creation.

(Another major spoiler regarding if it would be possible to stop time itself:)

 Much later in the books, the Dark One expresses frustration of not being able to undo time itself - the effects of balefire, more precisely. Throughout the books, both Aes Sedai as well as the (sane) Forsaken express fear of using balefire and it actually seems that neither side has anything to gain from destroying time itself, though it is hinted from both sides that balefire could cause that to happen.

 The very ending of the books suggests that destroying time itself wasn't really the Dark One's motive either. It rather seems that it was just a goal that Ishamael's broken mind came up with and particularly insisted on during his incarnation as Ba'alzamon. In his later incarnation as Moridin, he seems less fanatic about this but has still not given up the idea.

